# Maven 3: override command line in POM

Tags: command-line, maven-3, overriding, tycho, maven-surefire-plugin

We can override properties defined in POM using command line.

Can we somehow make the opposite effect? To override command line parameters in POM?

I have a Hudson with "-Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests -DskipITs" in command line, and I can't change it (admin responds to requests in a month), but I want to run my tests anyway..

Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

Something you might try: Change your POM to execute the tests as part of another phase in the lifecycle.  I don't know how to do this off-hand, but in the worst-case you could always use `<ant>` to shoehorn it in.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you @jimbojw, maybe I will do that.. (but that are really worst cases)

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the configuration for ignoring the test in the pom explicit.